# What is exactly the pH value of distilled water?

Tags: water, ph

This was asked by one of my students in my class. I know it is the pH of 7, but others say it can be 6.55 pH

Comment: And I say it's 6.2. What others say is not an argument. Atmospheric gases are dissolved in distilled water (mainly oxygen, nitrogen, argon, carbon dioxide). Due to dissolved carbon dioxide, distilled water has a weakly acid medium and its pH is typically between 6 and 7. It vastly depends on how it's stored and what the ambient conditions are.

Comment: Does it depend on the temperature?

Comment: Of course it does https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39608/effect-of-temperature-on-ph-of-water

Comment: Yep, it does, and quite significantly. The solubility of $\ce{CO2}$ decreases with the increase of the water temperature ([A page ripped off from CRC Handbook](http://sites.chem.colostate.edu/diverdi/all_courses/CRC%20reference%20data/solubility%20of%20carbon%20dioxide%20in%20water.pdf) which you can use to support your explanation to the students).

Comment: So for *pure* distilled water at $25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ the pH would be 7.00. But the [$K_\mathrm w$ is a function of temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water) and hence the pH of *pure* water will vary with temperature too. The problem is that *ordinary* distilled water will contain some dissolved $\ce{CO2}$ which will lower the pH. You have to take extra precautions not to get $\ce{CO2}$ dissolved in the distilled water.

Comment: I just measured battery water for pH 5.5 and EC 1 µS/cm at 21 °C, using calibrated lab equipment. It was quite hard to get a stable pH reading because distilled water doesn't have enough ions for the probe to work reliably. As others have stated, the acidity is caused by CO2 absorbed from air.

Answer (score 5):

keep in mind that water (distilled, deionized, or tap) is NOT "pure" (i.e., pH equal to 7). The moment it comes in contact with air, CO2 gas begins dissolving into it, forming carbonic acid. The actual pH, therefore, will often be slightly less than 7.

Comment: The pH of water in equilibrium with aerial CO2 is reportedly 5.65.( or less due raising CO2 level )