# pH value of distilled (pure) water

Tags: ph

What is exactly the pH value of distilled water?

which is correct?

- Neutral(not acidic not alkaline)pH 7?
- pH 6?

Comment: This is a different question. You just edited your last question  and made it into something else. It would have been better if you had created a new question...............

Comment: You really should not do so ... The comments (which now have been deleted) seemed so confusing after you changed the entire question.

Answer (score 1):

Distilled water usually has a pH of 7. However, pH might change with temperature. See [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/39610/48829) for more detail.